# Why does RestTemplate not urlencode the '+' symbol but urlencodes everything else?

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I've found a strange problem where the urlencoding behaves inconsistently.

*UPDATE*

There are differences between Spring MVC versions 4.3 and 5.1:

```
// FAIL in MVC 4.x 
@Test
public void test2() {
    rt.getForObject("http://localhost/expr={expr}", String.class, "x/y");
    Assert.assertEquals("http://localhost/expr=x%2Fy", savedUri.toString());
}

// FAIL in MVC 4 or 5
@Test
public void test3() {
    rt.getForObject("http://localhost/expr={expr}", String.class, "x+y");
    Assert.assertEquals("http://localhost/expr=x%2By", savedUri.toString());
}

// ok in MVC 4.x, FAIL in MVC 5
@Test
public void test4() {
    rt.getForObject("http://localhost/expr={expr}", String.class, "x+y");
    Assert.assertEquals("http://localhost/expr=x+y", savedUri.toString());
}
```

This may have been part of a larger ref*ctoring of Spring MVC, as it also manifests in a totally different place [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56419865/handling-of-in-requestparameter-changed-between-spring-mvc-4-x-and-5-x-how)

**Question Details**

My question is best illustrated by the following self-contained test. Don't be intimidated by the `ClientHttpRequestFactory` - the important part are the last 2 test methods.

```
package com.stackoverflow.questions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.commons.io.input.ReaderInputStream;
import org.apache.commons.io.output.WriterOutputStream;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

public class RestTemplateTest {

    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

    WriterOutputStream writerOutputStream = new WriterOutputStream(stringWriter);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

    URI savedUri;

    ClientHttpRequestFactory rf = new ClientHttpRequestFactory() {
        @Override
        public ClientHttpRequest createRequest(URI uri, HttpMethod httpMethod) throws IOException {
            savedUri = uri;
            return new ClientHttpRequest() {
                @Override
                public OutputStream getBody() throws IOException {
                    return writerOutputStream;
                }

                @Override
                public HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
                    return headers;
                }

                @Override
                public URI getURI() {
                    return uri;
                }

                @Override
                public String getMethodValue() {
                    return httpMethod.name();
                }

                @Override
                public ClientHttpResponse execute() throws IOException {

                    writerOutputStream.close();

                    return new ClientHttpResponse() {
                        @Override
                        public HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
                            return new HttpHeaders();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public InputStream getBody() throws IOException {
                            return new ReaderInputStream(new StringReader("test"));
                        }

                        @Override
                        public String getStatusText() throws IOException {
                            return "OK";
                        }

                        @Override
                        public HttpStatus getStatusCode() throws IOException {
                            return HttpStatus.OK;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public int getRawStatusCode() throws IOException {
                            return 200;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void close() {
                        }
                    };
                }
            };
        }
    };
    RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate(rf);

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        String resp = rt.getForObject("http://whatever", String.class);
        Assert.assertEquals("test", resp);
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        rt.getForObject("http://localhost/expr={expr}", String.class, "x/y");
        Assert.assertEquals("http://localhost/expr=x%2Fy", savedUri.toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void test3() {
        rt.getForObject("http://localhost/expr={expr}", String.class, "x+y");
        Assert.assertEquals("http://localhost/expr=x%2By", savedUri.toString());
    }

}
```

**What's happening:**

- division symbol `/` is properly encoded to a `%2F` - test2() passes
- addition symbol `+` is NOT encoded to a `%2B` - it remains `+` and test3() fails

**What should happen:**

test3() should pass. The `+` should be encoded to %2B because `+` is a special character in URLs and is interpreted as a white space by many server-side web frameworks.

**What is going on here and is there a generic fix?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's uncertainty whether `+` should be encoded or not.  Older RFCs say yes, newer ones say maybe.

Try setting the encoding mode as follows:

```java
  DefaultUriBuilderFactory builderFactory = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory();
  builderFactory.setEncodingMode(EncodingMode.VALUES_ONLY);
  restTemplate.setUriTemplateHandler(builderFactory);
```

See [SPR-19394](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/19394) and [SPR-20750](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20750) for discussion.